# Which HTML5 elements have onload/"load event"?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, standards

[Mozilla's MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) informs about the  *load Event* with this stub:

> The load event is fired when a resource and its dependent resources
>   have finished loading.

and links to

[standard 1](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-load), which informs

> Trusted Targets:  Window, Document, Element

It seems that the related `onload` handler, and the `load` event is hence designed to work with Element. It seems such an element is `<img>` to indicate the loading of this.

*Please note that I now that the `load` event on the window/document indicates also the load state of its contained Elements* but some [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element) can

a) change their `src`/`href` property (`<img>`, `<script>`, `<link>`,....)
b) or their inline content (`<style>`, `<script>`)

dynamically at a later state.

With this question I seek help knowing "which Elements support the `load` Event, `onload`.Handler.

I tested this in Chromium and Firefox and it seems it is supported in 
`<style>`, `<script>`

```
var styleElement = document.createElement("style");
styleElement.onload = function() { 
    console.log("styleElement onload called");
};
document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
// output: "styleElement onload called";
```

but I am unsure if the discovered behavior is actually anywhere specified in the stanards?

Comment: _"A user agent MUST dispatch this event when the DOM implementation finishes loading the resource (such as the document) and any dependent resources (such as images, style sheets, or scripts)."_ ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-load))

Comment: @Andreas , would that include both `src`-type and *importantly also* inline-content resources therefore? Also I was not really sure about what actually qualifies as a `dependent resource`, for instance `<video>` or `<audio>` or `<iframe>`, tags seem to qualify as well, without being explicityly mentioned. This "doubt" hence is kind of the reason for the question. Thanks for adding this content, that imporves the question

Answer (score 1):

**Supported HTML tags are as follows :**     <body>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, 
<link>, <script>, <style>

I tested it on <h1> tag but it didn't work out

```
<h1 onload="myFunction()">Hello World!</h1>;
```

For more details, visit [W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

Comment: Your answer states what elements you can use the event with and then you show an example using a non-supported element along with "I tried it but it didn't work.".